# Laravel namespace and file path is not match

Tags: php, laravel

I've just moved a few class files to another directory without changing namespace inside those files. I've also make a file using same namespace that I already used on moved files. I believe that it caused namespace and file-path issue of my app.

Currently, when I create a class `App\ItsmModule\StatMachine`, app tries to open `App\ItsmModule\backup\StateMachine`.

How do I fix this issue?
What should I know to avoid re-creating this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The reason is related somewhat of composer autoloading.

As far as I know, composer stores the list of dependency chains of all using files. Most case, I think I don't need update this list because the list somehow updated by [unknown update detector].

Anyway, I solve this problem via update the list using `composer dump-autoload` on console.